# Powershell Parameters

Tags: url, powershell, escaping, character

I am extreme newbie to powershell.  I have a script that I want to pass a URL as a parameter.   The url runs a PHP process that creates and downloads a PDF file then the script prints the pdf and then deletes the pdf.   I cannot get the URL parm to work.

Below is my script

```
$w=$args[0] 

Start $w

$Directory = "C:\Users\pslessor\downloads\"

Get-ChildItem -path $Directory -recurse -include *.pdf | ForEach-Object {Start-Process -FilePath $_.fullname -Verb Print -PassThru | %{sleep 5;$_} | kill }

Remove-Item C:\Users\pslessor\downloads\* -include *.PDF
```

This script is being executed by a batch file PrintPl.bat

```
SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%PrintPl.ps1
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PowerShellScriptPath%' %1";
```

And I am testing with testprint.bat

```
C:\Wget\PrintPl "https://partners.wayfair.com/print_shipping_docs.php?Print=1&printPackingSlips=1&PackingSlipPOs=CS287851107"
```

The URL is all in one string this editor is forcing the line feed at .php?

The Error I am getting is 
The string starting:

```
At Line:1 Char:25
+ & 'C:\Wget\Printpl.ps1'   <<<< 'https://partners.wayfair.com/print_shipping_docs.php?print;
is missing the terminator: '.
At line:1 Char:85 
+ & 'C:\Wget\PrintPl.psl' 'https://partners.wayfair.com/print_shipping_docs.php
?print; <<<<

    + CategoryInfo      :ParserError: <https://partner...docs.php?print;:
String> [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
  + FullyqualifiedErrorid : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

'printPackingSlips' is not recognaized as internal or external command,
Operable program or batch file.
'PackingSlipPOs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch File
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when you pass the arguments the command interpreter expands your variables and see this:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& 'C:\Wget\PrintPl.ps1' https://partners.wayfair.com/print_shipping_docs.php?    Print=1&printPackingSlips=1&PackingSlipPOs=CS287851107"
```

So the command that it is trying to execute is C:\Wget\PrintPl.ps1, and it assumes that what comes next are arguments. Since what it is passed has a space, and is not enclosed in quotes or double quotes it assumes that it is multiple arguments. It sees it as:

Execute this script: C:\Wget\PrintPl.ps1
With the following arguments:

- $Args[0]=?
- $Args[1]=Print=1&printPackingSlips=1&PackingSlipPOs=CS287851107

To stop this from happening you will need to enclose the URL in quotes as well, so your command should look like this:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PowerShellScriptPath%' '%1'"
```

**Edit:** Ok, that didn't work for your case. So we're going to change this a little bit. Instead of -Command I'm going to suggest you use -File. So your Powershell execution line within the batch file will look like this:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%PowerShellScriptPath%" %*
```

You should be able to run the  batch file exactly as you previously had been. I'm fairly confident that will work for you.

Comment: Actually the URL is just one line and there are no spaces for what ever reason the editor to this site split my line and will not let me put it back together.   I did enclose %1 in single quotes and that did solve the error at character 25 however still getting the error at 85.

Comment: like the errormessage tells you: `TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString`. `'C:\Wget\PrintPl.psl' 'https://partners.wayfair.com/print_shipping_docs.php` you are not closing the quotes here

Comment: No Paul, that's not it. It's the batch command interpreter that's mangling his string.

Comment: Looks like the = sign is causing the issue.  Makes powershell think the parm stops at print when it should be print=1.

Comment: Answer updated, I think this should be a winner. I can get PS to at least echo back the correct URL to me now when I run it as described in my updated answer.

Comment: I think this is getting closer the & character look to still be an issue.

Comment: I had to brute force it.    I changed the & character to ! on my call and then in my script i added the following.
$w = $w -replace  "!", "&"  now the url is correct loads to the browser then just sits there never connects.